# How do not scan all records to query top rows by complex condition

Tags: sql, sql-server, indexing, sql-execution-plan

I have a table and data like this:

```
create table AmountObjects
(
  objectId integer,
  unixTimestamp integer,
  amount integer,

  PRIMARY KEY  
  (
      [objectId] ASC,
      [unixTimestamp] ASC  
  )
);

insert into AmountObjects values (1, 1, 33);
insert into AmountObjects values (1, 2, 33);
insert into AmountObjects values (1, 3, 33);
insert into AmountObjects values (1, 4, 33);
insert into AmountObjects values (1, 5, 33);
insert into AmountObjects values (1, 6, 33);
insert into AmountObjects values (1, 7, 33);
insert into AmountObjects values (1, 8, 33);
insert into AmountObjects values (1, 9, 33);
insert into AmountObjects values (1, 10, 33);
```

I want to query last records filtered by date and cumulative amount, but queries like this scan all records by object:

```
select 
    a.objectId,
    a.unixTimestamp,
    a.amount,
    s.total
from AmountObjects a
cross apply
(
    select sum(amount) total from AmountObjects stat 
    where a.unixTimestamp <= stat.unixTimestamp and a.objectId = stat.objectId 
) s
where 
    unixTimestamp >= 9
    or s.total <= 150
```

My question is: **how to query data without scann all data by object**?

Thanks

Comment: @MartinSmith not from start, I need last operations with total amount of 150 no need to scan all history

Comment: Are all the amounts positive integers?

Comment: @MartinSmith, yes only positive values

Comment: Maybe with an indexed column (or an index on a computed column, if an indexed column still doesn't exist in sql server), or an indexed view?

Comment: @johey - none of those will help. There is no way of indexing a running total column as a computed column (as the calculation is data dependant and so not deterministic) or of including it in an indexed view due to the many restrictions on indexed views

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only way I can think of doing this involves running the backwards running total twice. Once to get the target timestamp below which should be ignored (short circuited with the `TOP 1`) and then again to get the running totals for values above that (uses a seek to only get the range of rows above that).

Unless you have a very high proportion of rows to ignore this is unlikely to be an improvement over the simpler approach of just calculating the running total for everything and discarding what you don't need.

```
WITH DistinctObjects
     AS (SELECT DISTINCT objectId
         FROM   AmountObjects a),
     MinTimeStampsByObjectId
     AS (SELECT do.objectId,
                ca.minUnixTimeStamp
         FROM   DistinctObjects do
                CROSS APPLY (SELECT ISNULL((SELECT TOP 1 unixTimeStamp
                                            FROM   (SELECT *,
                                                           SUM(ao.amount)
                                                             OVER (
                                                               ORDER BY ao.unixTimeStamp DESC) AS total
                                                    FROM   AmountObjects ao
                                                    WHERE  ao.objectId = do.objectId) d
                                            WHERE  total > 150
                                            ORDER  BY d.unixTimeStamp DESC), -1))ca(minUnixTimeStamp))
SELECT ca2.*
FROM   MinTimeStampsByObjectId mts
       CROSS APPLY (SELECT *,
                           SUM(ao.amount)
                             OVER (
                               ORDER BY ao.unixTimeStamp DESC) AS total
                    FROM   AmountObjects ao
                    WHERE  ao.objectId = mts.objectId
                           AND ao.unixTimeStamp > IIF(mts.minUnixTimeStamp > 8,8,mts.minUnixTimeStamp)) ca2
```

Comment: Great, for most of my cases this workaround are good solution, double scan of month beter than one scan of years

Answer (score 1):

This should implement the same logic and be more efficient:

```
select a.*
from (select a.objectId, a.unixTimestamp, a.amount,
             sum(a.amount) over (partition by a.objectId order by a.unixTimeStamp desc) as total
      from AmountObjects a
     ) a
where unixTimestamp >= 9 or total <= 150;
```

However, it will still scan all the rows.

Comment: Thanks,  I also use window functions in production code, any way this query give the same query plan. Is any way to force index scan with exit condition?

Comment: @gabba . . . Wow.  SQL Server did put in a really good optimizer for `apply`.  I cannot readily think of a way of short-circuiting the operation.  If you want only one row, then you can add `top (1)` and see if that improves performance.

Comment: unfortunately I need to all records by specific condition