# Where clause on Running total

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2014

I have this table which stores containers by region and the number of coffee pouches in each of the containers.

```
if object_id( 'dbo.Container' ) is not null
    drop table dbo.Container
go

create table dbo.Container
(
    Id   int not null,
    Region int not null,
    NumberOfCoffeePouches int not null,
    constraint pkc_Container__Id primary key clustered(Id asc)
)
go

insert into dbo.Container 
    ( Id , Region , NumberOfCoffeePouches ) 
values 
    ( 1, 1, 10 ),
    ( 2, 1, 30 ),
    ( 3, 1, 5),
    ( 4, 1, 7),
    ( 5, 1, 1),
    ( 6, 1, 3),
    ( 7, 2, 4),
    ( 8, 2, 4),
    ( 9, 2, 4)
```

I need to list out the container Ids that will be used to fulfill an order of, say 50, coffee pouches. Over supplying is OK.

Here is query I have come up with

```
declare @RequiredCoffeePouches int = 50

select
        sq2.Id,
        sq2.NumberOfCoffeePouches,
        sq2.RunningTotal,
        sq2.LagRunningTotal
from
    (
        select
            sq1.Id,
            sq1.NumberOfCoffeePouches,
            sq1.RunningTotal,
            lag(sq1.RunningTotal, 1, 0) over (order by sq1.Id asc) 
                as 'LagRunningTotal'
        from
            (
                select
                    c.Id,
                    c.NumberOfCoffeePouches,
                    sum(c.NumberOfCoffeePouches) 
                        over (order by c.Id asc) as 'RunningTotal'
                from
                    dbo.Container as c
                where
                    c.Region = 1
            ) as sq1
    ) as sq2
where
    sq2.LagRunningTotal <= @RequiredCoffeePouches
```

It gives the expected result

```
Id          NumberOfCoffeePouches RunningTotal LagRunningTotal
----------- --------------------- ------------ ---------------
1           10                    10           0
2           30                    40           10
3           5                     45           40
4           7                     52           45
```

Question:

1. Is there a better and more optimized way to achieve this?
2. Specially the Container table is very large table and I think the sub query sq1 will unnecessarily calculate the RunningTotals for all the containers in the region. I was wondering if there is anyway to have sq1 stop processing more rows once the RunnningTotal exceeds over the @RequiredCoffeePouches.

Comment: In general it is not safe to stop. The running total can fall and rise with negative values. But even if they are constrained to be positive SQL Server still won't do this for you. You can run the query twice as here https://stackoverflow.com/a/53971884/73226

Answer (score -1):

Two things:

Moving your `WHERE` clause inside of the relevant sub-select can greatly increase the speed of the query because it'll pull less data. Using your example:

```
SELECT
    sq2.Id,
    sq2.NumberOfCoffeePouches,
    sq2.RunningTotal,
    sq2.LagRunningTotal
FROM
    (
    SELECT
        sq1.Id,
        sq1.NumberOfCoffeePouches,
        sq1.RunningTotal,
        lag(sq1.RunningTotal, 1, 0) over (order by sq1.Id asc) AS 'LagRunningTotal'
    FROM
        (
         SELECT
             c.Id,
             c.NumberOfCoffeePouches,
             SUM(c.NumberOfCoffeePouches) OVER (order by c.Id asc) AS 'RunningTotal'
         FROM dbo.Container AS c
         WHERE c.Region = 1
        ) AS sq1
    WHERE sq2.LagRunningTotal <= @RequiredCoffeePouches
) AS sq2
```

CTEs can also improve performance:

```
;WITH sql1CTE AS (
    SELECT
        c.Id,
        c.NumberOfCoffeePouches,
        SUM(c.NumberOfCoffeePouches) OVER (order by c.Id asc) AS 'RunningTotal'
    FROM dbo.Container AS c
    WHERE c.Region = 1
),
sql2CTE AS (
SELECT
        Id,
        NumberOfCoffeePouches,
        RunningTotal,
        lag(RunningTotal, 1, 0) over (order by Id asc) AS 'LagRunningTotal'
FROM sql1CTE
WHERE LagRunningTotal <= @RequiredCoffeePouches
)
SELECT
    Id,
    NumberOfCoffeePouches,
    RunningTotal,
    LagRunningTotal
FROM sql2CTE
```

[SQL Server CTE Basics](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/t-sql-programming/sql-server-cte-basics/)

If you're using SSMS, select "Include Client Statistics" and "Include Actual Execution Plan" to keep track of how your query performs while you're crafting it.

Comment: CTEs have no performance advantage over derived tables. And SQL Server can generally push predicates down into derived tables when safe to do so.

Comment: In this instance the predicate is required to be as it is anyway as it references an alias not in scope for the `WHERE` where you have placed it